# Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': Le chargement de version test des applications n’est pas activé sur ce site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, provider-hosted-app, visual-studio-2013

I want to deploy a provider hosted app in office 365(SharePoint 2013 online),when I published the app I found it in my app catalog.But there is an error in visual studio 2013 that I coudn't resolve it.

> "Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': 
>    Le chargement de version test des applications n’est pas activé sur ce
>    site. "

In English:

> "Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint':The Application test version of loading is not enabled on this site

Has someone experienced the same and found a solution please?

Answer (score 2):

Loading Apps directly from Visual Studio only works if the destination is a Developer site.In order to overcome this issue you need to enable the Developer feature on your Site collection where you want to deploy and test your apps using Visual Studio.

[Debugging Apps for SharePoint Online on a non-development site collection](http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/debugging-apps-for-sharepoint-online/)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/how24/archive/2013/06/14/prepare-your-sharepoint-2013-farm-for-app-development-and-debugging.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I installed the SharePoint Management Shell but should I write all the java script file mentioned in the first tutorial? it's not so clear,how I will configure the office 365 to accept provider hosted apps?

Comment: I think that the second tutorial you gave talk about SharePoint foundation.I am working with SharePoint online. I can't resolve my problem !